# Why doesn't my For loop create more than one object on the screen?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, for-loop

Having a bit of a problem. I'm trying to add 10 items to the stage but it is only adding 1. Any insight on what I'm doing wrong?

```
        public var numCells:Array = [];
        public function addCell():void
        {
            var cell:Cell = new Cell();
            var i:int = 0;
            cell.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1366);
            cell.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 768);
            for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                numCells.push(cell);
                addChild(cell);
            }
            return;
        }
```

Comment: How have you determined that it "keeps going forever"? The code you posted would not exhibit this behavior. Something else is going on.

Comment: that method can't do that unless you are calling it forever.

Comment: Have you added any trace statements to this code?  If `addCell()` is being called repeatedly, it would look like an infinite loop.  Also, calling `addChild()` with the same cell repeatedly looks very strange.  Are you trying to repeatedly add the same element on purpose?

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks. I overlooked where I put addCell() and it's not repeating anymore. However it doesn't place 10 items. It's only placing 1.

Comment: As @Brian said, you are repeating `addChild()` of the same `cell`, which does not duplicate the display object each time. The net effect is as if you added it once. You should create new `Cell` instance within the loop if you want to end up with 10 instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only ever instantiating one cell.  calling `addChild` a second time with the same object passed in doesn't make a copy of that object, it just moves it to the top most 'layer'.

You need to instantiate a new cell inside the for loop.  Something like this:

```
     private function addCells():void {
         for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++){
             var cell:Cell = new Cell();
             cell.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1366);
             cell.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 768);

             numCells.push(cell);
             addChild(cell);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm still learning... I saw you answered another one of my very dumb questions, so thank you for that also.